# Mysql INSER INTO with SELECT and INNER JOIN WITH CASE

Tags: mysql

The following code reads:

```
--Code Created by Michael Berkowski
create table dvd (
   dvd_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  );
INSERT INTO dvd VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

CREATE TABLE dvd_price (
   dvd_price_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   dvd_id INT NOT NULL,
   rental_amount INT,
   time_rented_for VARCHAR(10) 
);

INSERT INTO dvd_price (dvd_id, rental_amount, time_rented_for)
  SELECT
    dvd_id,
    2 AS rental_amount,
    rental_period
  FROM
    dvd
    CROSS JOIN (

      -- This is where I'm having issues
      SELECT (CASE dvd.dvd_id
                WHEN dvd.dvd_id = 1
                THEN '1-Day'
                ELSE '3-Day'
              END) AS rental_period
  ) rental_periods
```

Why can I not do a CASE statement after the CROSS JOIN and how would I fix this?
I get the error, "Unknown table 'dvd' in field list:", what is a better way of writing this?

Comment: `dvd` table is unknown in this subquery. Please explain what do you trying to do, why cross join ?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to do some data fabrication, in this case I am trying insert data when the dvd_id = 1, then insert into rental_period '1-Day' otherwise all the other dvd_id's insert '3-Day' if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO dvd_price (dvd_id, rental_amount, time_rented_for)
  SELECT
    dvd_id,
    2 AS rental_amount,
    CASE dvd.dvd_id
                WHEN dvd.dvd_id = 1
                THEN '1-Day'
                ELSE '3-Day'
              END
  FROM
    dvd
```